# Trying to create headless Pi through Mac

Tags: ssh

I found my IP address for the pi, it is on and clearly connected to the network but when I try to ping into it I get this message 
this in terminal

```
Annas-Macbook-2:~ apple$ ping 192.168.2.33
PING 192.168.2.33 (192.168.2.33): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
76 bytes from d226-13-85.home.cgocable.net (24.226.13.85): Destination Net Unreachable
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 5400 1e22   0 0000  3e  01 db06 192.168.0.15  192.168.2.33

Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
76 bytes from d226-13-85.home.cgocable.net (24.226.13.85): Destination Net Unreachable
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 5400 ac66   0 0000  3e  01 4cc2 192.168.0.15  192.168.2.33

Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
Request timeout for icmp_seq 9
Request timeout for icmp_seq 10
Request timeout for icmp_seq 11
Request timeout for icmp_seq 12
Request timeout for icmp_seq 13
Request timeout for icmp_seq 14
Request timeout for icmp_seq 15
Request timeout for icmp_seq 16
Request timeout for icmp_seq 17
Request timeout for icmp_seq 18
Request timeout for icmp_seq 19
Request timeout for icmp_seq 20
Request timeout for icmp_seq 21
Request timeout for icmp_seq 22
Request timeout for icmp_seq 23
Request timeout for icmp_seq 24
Request timeout for icmp_seq 25
Request timeout for icmp_seq 26
76 bytes from d226-13-85.home.cgocable.net (24.226.13.85): Destination Net Unreachable
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 5400 8bf4   0 0000  3e  01 6d34 192.168.0.15  192.168.2.33

Request timeout for icmp_seq 27
Request timeout for icmp_seq 28
Request timeout for icmp_seq 29
Request timeout for icmp_seq 30
Request timeout for icmp_seq 31
Request timeout for icmp_seq 32
Request timeout for icmp_seq 33
Request timeout for icmp_seq 34
Request timeout for icmp_seq 35
Request timeout for icmp_seq 36
Request timeout for icmp_seq 37
Request timeout for icmp_seq 38
Request timeout for icmp_seq 39
Request timeout for icmp_seq 40
Request timeout for icmp_seq 41
Request timeout for icmp_seq 42
Request timeout for icmp_seq 43
Request timeout for icmp_seq 44
Request timeout for icmp_seq 45
Request timeout for icmp_seq 46
Request timeout for icmp_seq 47
Request timeout for icmp_seq 48
Request timeout for icmp_seq 49
Request timeout for icmp_seq 50
Request timeout for icmp_seq 51
```

And then when I try to SSH it says:

```
Annas-Macbook-2:~ apple$ ssh pi@192.168.0.24
The authenticity of host '192.168.0.24 (192.168.0.24)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 14:1e:36:8d:95:34:60:34:81:b2:33:78:2e:72:f3:06.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Comment: First off, you are pinging 192.168.2.33 and ssh'ing 192.168.0.24 -That doesn't make sense.   If you are wondering about the last line, yes it's generally safe to accept that warning, it simply means you haven't made this connection to this machine before, if you are  worried about security and this is travelling over the internet then more secure verification steps might be in order.  But if it's just on your local network and you know already it's your pi then just say yes.

Comment: How did you find the IP address?

Comment: and what is your internal ip address and netmask? run ifconfig -a in the terminal to find out

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you enter 'yes' to the SSH prompt though?

You are playing with two different IP addresses, this could be the problem. Best way to get the IP is logging into your router and checking for the right one. If you can't do this for some reason, try this:

I would assume you are wirelessly connected to the same router/hub with your RPI

1. Run terminal on your mac and do `ifconfig | grep "inet "`
2. You should see two lines, one with local loopback (127.0.0.1) and another one with the IP obtained from the router (192.168.XXX.XXX)
3. Check that the IP you are trying to reach is within the same subnet with yours (only the last number on the IP should be different)
4. Another way to check if you are on the same network is doing a traceroute  to this IP - should be one hop, not many.
5. SSH to it and answer "yes" when it's asking you if you want to establish the connection.